# Датой, как фильтр в запросе, берущаяся из соседней таблицы mySQL

Tags: mysql, запрос, дата

К примеру, есть таблица тип встреч, в ней есть числовое поле "время на которое можно просрочить событие", в минутах. Есть таблица событий, где есть срок событий. Как выбрать события, которые просрочились более чем на "время_..."

```
SELECT * FROM crmTasks
WHERE
  (
       date(crmTaskDueDate) < date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL - **crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin** MIN)
  )
```

Такая конструкция не работает...

Comment: А просто `curdate() - INTERVAL ...` ?  И старайтесь делать запросы так, что бы не применять функцию к колонке таблицы, т.е. что бы было просто crmTaskDueDate, а не date() от нее. Вы вынуждаете, применяя функцию, оптимизатор делать полное сканирование таблицы, даже если у вас есть индекс по колонке с датой

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду. Там смысл, что у разных типов встреч - разное это время, поэтому не могу написать "curdate - 10 minute", к примеру

Comment: А вам нужно я так понял именно с округлением по дате ? т.е. если на 10 минут зашли в предыдущие сутки - то надо взять сразу с начало тех суток ? Мне почему то кажется, что если отсчет в минутах то надо и время учитывать, использовать например now() вместо curdate()

Comment: О! нет, мне НЕ нужно округление по дате, сейчас пойду читать мануалы по date() видимо ошибка именно в этом!!

Comment: Тогда да, применяйте now()-interval X minute. curdate() дает голую дату. now() дает текущую дату и время

Comment: Все! Супер! Спасибо! с уточнением, из комментария @cheops все заработало. TIMESTAMP( crmTaskDueDate ) < TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin *60 !!! эта штука срабатывает очень эпизодически, поэтому могу себе позволить не оптимизированный запрос.. СПАСИБО ВСЕМ!

Comment: Хм. А без timestamp, в виде now()-interval не работает ? там таймстамп как бы не к чему

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE crmTasks
 INNER JOIN crmTaskTypes ON crmTasks.crmTasksTypeId = crmTaskTypes.crmTaskTypeId
 SET
 crmTasksStateId=9, crmTasksResultId=2
 ,crmTaskDueDate=date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL - 1 HOUR)
  WHERE
  (TIMESTAMP( crmTaskDueDate ) < TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin *60)
```

Вот окончательное решение. Спасибо @Mike и @cheops
(репутации пока не хватает отметить ваши ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, переведите время в секунды и вычтите из них значение `crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin` помноженное на 60. Далее сравнивайте эти значения.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  crmTasks
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP(date(crmTaskDueDate) < TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin * 60
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что залезть в мою голову/базу/запрос сложно, но что-то я делаю не так.... TIMESTAMP(date(crmTaskDueDate) показывает 2016-08-08 09:05:00 а (TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin*60)
 показывает 20160807999100 и сравнивать явно не хочет, вернее не то, что "не хочет", не выдает строчки, которые по логике должен

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM crmTasks
 WHERE crmTaskDueDate < now() - INTERVAL **crmTaskTypeNormaTimeMin** MINUTE
```